# OpenVPN in visual studio and ec2

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, amazon-ec2, vpn, openvpn

I am new to open VPN and I need to connect to sql through open VPN from my mvc application, obviously I know the credentials and settings of the vpn I need to connect to. Could you advise me on the most efficient way to do this operation? Since my application is mounted on an ec2 windows instance...

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is not related to the <sql> _language_.)

Comment: @jarlh i am using management studio